# Django Rest Framework, Rest API with custom pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework.
I have the following situation:

I have a table with some elements (for example 10k elements).
I also have an unique index in this model:

```
....
Element i-1
Element i
Element i+1
Element i+2
....
```

I need to have a REST API with the following response:

> GET Elements by center Index: **i**

and I need to return a set of result that contains **N** elements that are before and **N** elements that are after the element **i** .

Using the pagination is possible to navigate in this set of results:
Using PREV I can request the previous page and using NEXT I can request the next page...
Example:

> Get elements by center index = i

```
PREV:....

Result:
[
Element k
Element k+1
......
Element i
......
Element w
Element w+1
]
NEXT:....
```

Comment: Hey, @Safari, I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

In [DRF documentation on pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) is stated that it is possible to write a custom pagination method:

> To create a custom pagination serializer class you should subclass
>   `pagination.BasePagination` and override the `paginate_queryset(self,
>   queryset, request, view=None)` and `get_paginated_response(self, data)`
>   methods:
>
> - The `paginate_queryset` method is passed the initial queryset and
>     should return an iterable object that contains only the data in the  >requested page.
> - The `get_paginated_response` method is passed the serialized page data
>     and should return a Response instance

So we are going to do just that:

**BASIC EXAMPLE**

```
from rest_framework.pagination import BasePagination


class CenterPointPagination(BasePagination):
    default_center = 0
    default_radius = 5
    center_query_param = 'center'
    radius_query_param = 'radius'        

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        center = request.get(center_query_param, default_center)
        radius = request.get(radius_query_param, default_radius)

        start = center - radius if center - radius > 0 else 0
        finish = center + radius
        return list(queryset[start:finish])

    def get_paginated_resposne(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            'center': center,
            'radius': radius,
            'results': data
        ]))
```

That pretty much is what you need as a base. 
You will have to customize it further to suite your needs.
To get some ideas on how to do that, have a look at the source code of

- [LimitOffsetPagination](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L319)
- [PageNumberPagination](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L166)
- and everything else in [pagination](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py)